# How to create a fixed CSS3 header?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create my first website manually, and I have a few questions on how to do things. Please note I want to accomplish this in pure HTML5, no JS. All I have right now is a navigation header, which should stay fixed at the top of the page no matter how far one scrolls. However, in order to get an image to respect this header size, I've had to resort to using css in the following manner:

Is there a a more elegant way to accomplish this?

```
body
{
overflow: hidden;
}
header {
height: 20vh;
}
main {
height: 80vh;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Whether you think that is more or less elegant is up to you.

Comment: Please put your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show what have you done so far.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
position:fixed;
```

to the css of any element that you want to stick to the screen.

in your case. probably,

```
header {
height: 20vh;
position:fixed;
}
```